# MySQL Join where matched columns contain different values

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, subquery

The below Select used to work perfectly using Mysql_Select with a for loop however since updating to mysqli_connect and using a while loop I've hit a snag.

```
$query = 
    "SELECT * 
    FROM 
        jobs
        LEFT JOIN invoices ON jobs.jobID=invoices.jobID
    WHERE jobs.customerID = '$selectedcustID' 
    ORDER BY date_auto DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {          
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $selectedjobID = $row["jobID"];
        $date = $row["date_auto"];
        $formatdate =  date("d/m/Y", $date);
        $status = $row["status"];
        $notes = $row["notes"];
        $invoiceStatus = $row["invoiceStatus"];
        $invoicePaid = $row["paid"];
        $invoiceNumber = $row["invoiceID"];
        $formatinvoiceNumber = sprintf("%05d", $invoiceNumber);
```

The common parameter is the `jobID` column in the `jobs` and `invoices` tables but, as the invoice will not exist until raised, the display of the `jobID` in my php output list of jobs is now blank.  I think the reason is that it is using the invoices version of jobID (being `NULL`) rather than the jobs version.

I've tried all kinds of ways of working around this but am running round in circles.  I'm thinking that it will be a case of saying SELECT * from jobs and SELECT jobID AS but I'm not sure on the correct syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: side note - `or die(mysqli_error())` should be `or die(mysqli_error($connection))`, as `mysqli_error` requires the db connection.

Comment: You also should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the invoice will not exist until raised, the display of the jobID in my php output list of jobs is now blank

Don't use `SELECT *` : you have a `jobID` field on both ends of the `LEFT JOIN`, and you end up with the wrong field being picked (ie `invoices.jobID`, which is `NULL` when the invoice was not yet raised).

You want to explicitely select the fields you need, like :

```
SELECT  
    jobs.jobID,
    ...
FROM 
    jobs 
    LEFT JOIN invoices ON jobs.jobID = invoices.jobID
 WHERE jobs.customerID = '$selectedcustID'
ORDER BY date_auto DESC
```

Comment: So something like this? Seems to work      `$query = "SELECT
          jobs.jobID,
          jobs.date_auto,
          jobs.status,
          jobs.notes,
          jobs.invoiceStatus,
          invoices.invoiceID,
          invoices.paid
          FROM
          jobs
          LEFT JOIN invoices ON jobs.jobID = invoices.jobID WHERE jobs.customerID = '$selectedcustID' ORDER BY date_auto DESC";
         $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
         }`

Comment: @TomJelfs : exactly. You got it.